# Thesis structure

Tags: chapters, thesis

I'm trying to structure my thesis in `LaTeX` using a template downloaded from an University site. 
The template is made by a "main" file that uses different `.tex` files for each chapter. 
When I work on a chapter to compile the file I have to assemble the "main" file. Since to avoid errors I'm used to compile every few minutes: this means that I have to waste a lot of time to exit the file I'm writing.
Is there an easier way?

Comment: If the files are included with `\include` you can say `\includeonly{file1,file2}` etc. in the preamble. I am pretty sure we have a lot of questions (and answers) for this

Comment: Some editors can handle a master file. For example texmaker, change to main.tex, select options and check: Make current file the master file. You can now compile while editing a  specific chapter.

Comment: No need to "exit the file" in most editors.  Do don't say anything about your environment, but in Vim I'd just run `!xelatex main` from the command line.

Comment: this seems to be a question about the editor you are using. Can you tell which one it is, or if you are looking for suggestions? Also, you may want to use `latexmk` and maybe you would like its `-pvc` option that automatically recompiles main whenever you save changes to any of the files involved

Comment: Tools like `latexmk` or (for Windows) `latexdaemon` allow for a ‘continuous’ preview  of the document you work on: each time a modification is saved, latex runs in the background and updates the resulting `.pdf`.

Comment: Using Texmaker with Mac OS X El capitan . If I'm understading correctly I have to change the preamble  of the chapter ?

Comment: You should not have preamble in your chapter files? One main file with the preamble, and the chapters input using either `\input` or `\include`. The content of the chapter file just as you would kept on writing in main.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Wanna scribble up an answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B: Done so!

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6):

One way to make partial compilations is to use `\include{...}` in the document body and `\includeonly{fileA,fileB,...}` in the preamble.

Only the files `fileA`, `fileB` etc. are included then.

`\include` preserves the reference labels, but introduces a new page, so it's predestinated for external files with `\chapter`.

There's also a `excludeonly` package, with `\excludeonly` command, that does basically the `set complement` of `\includeonly`.

Please note also, that there's usually no need to leave an editor, remove/compile something and enter the editor again (we're not in the late 70s or late 80s or early 1990s any longer ;-))

A personal statement: I don't like such split documents at all.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[innermargin=1.5cm,outermargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}% Before cleveref
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{filecontents}{introchapter.tex}
\chapter{Theory on Brontosaurs} \label{theory}


\begin{enumerate}
  \item Brontosaurs were large
  \item Brontosaurs are thin at one end, thick in the middle and thin again on the other end.
\end{enumerate}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents}{excavations.tex}
\chapter{Excavations of  Brontosaurs} \label{excavations}

After we stated the theory in \cref{theory} we want to provide you with the most exciting rules of excavating a Brontosaur.

This is the basic strategy:

\begin{itemize}
  \item Dig a hole
  \item Throw away anything that does not really resemble a Brontosaur
  \item In the very end you should have at least some parts of a Brontosaur
\end{itemize}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{results.tex}
\chapter{Results} \label{results}

We found that Brontosaurs are thin at one end, thick in the middle and thin again on the other end. Period!
\end{filecontents}


% Make sure to run the file first with this disabled, after that remove the % before \includeonly 
%\includeonly{excavations,results}


\title{Theory of Brontosaurs}
\author{Ann Elk (Misses)}
\date{April 05, 2063}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\include{introchapter}
\include{excavations}
\include{results}

\backmatter

% Other stuff here, e.g. Appendix, references etc. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: "A personal statement: I don't like such split documents at all." So if I understood well you prefer to have a long document only?

Comment: @LucatryingtowriteinLaTex: Apparently I seem to prefer long document only and you seem to prefer not accepting answers ;-)